# функция возвращает None, python

Tags: python, mongodb

у меня есть функция get_next_unique_id, которая берет uid из базы данных и если не находит его в базе данных то возвращает 1. Проблема в том что функция при любых условиях возвращает None. Я импортирую эту функцию в отдельный файл и использую её там. Вот код функции:

```
@log_this
def get_next_unique_id():
  
  # Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных и выбираем коллекцию
  cluster = MongoClient(TOKEN)
  collection = cluster.ordb.ordausers

  result = collection.find_one(sort=[('order._uid', pymongo.DESCENDING)])
  new_uid = result['order']['_uid'] + 1 if result else 1

  if new_uid:
    new_uid += 1
  else:
    new_uid = 1
    
  return new_uid
```

Я также проводил тест поместив в функцию этот код

```
def get_next_unique_id():
    x = 1
    return 1
```

она тоже возвращает **None**. Подскажите как это исправить? из-за чего это могло возникнуть?

вызов функции происходит так:

```
x = get_next_unique_id()
print(x)
```

Comment: Не возвращает:
```>>> def get_next_unique_id():
...     x = 1
...     return 1
>>> get_next_unique_id()
1```
Вы по всей видимости как-то криво вызываете свою функцию

Comment: ```
x = get_next_unique_id()
print(x)
```

Comment: ```>>> x = get_next_unique_id(); print(x)``` выводит 1

Comment: добавил в текст проблемы

Comment: https://python-fiddle.com/saved/Jrkqfe3uuQxH55WSTC43 не воспроизводится

Comment: Перед условием вывести в консоль new_uid пробовали?

Comment: пробовал, выводиться спокойно

Comment: @darth, этот код делает запрос в базу данных, для доступа к которой нужен токен

Comment: Переустановить питон пробовали? Ретурн так то должен работать 

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит попробовать добавить обработку ошибок, примерно как тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113947/how-to-properly-use-try-except-in-python

Comment: Покажите код декоратора `log_this`, что-то я подозреваю, что проблема в нём. Тест простой функции вы тоже с декоратором проводили или нет?